# What is the purpose of using ## in jquery

Tags: jquery

What is the purpose of using ## in jquery

```
if($('##hidetxt').val().length ==0 ){
                $("##hidetxt").val("firstname Asc");            
            }
```

What is the difference of using single # and double ## in jquery

Comment: Are you sure we can use `##` also..??I think NO

Comment: Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #. So the difference is that you are allowed to use single `#` and not allowed to use `##`.

Comment: Could you provide the context/HTML-section related with the code?

Comment: Couldn't it just be an escape character required by your backend programming language? Within `<cfoutput>` tags, ColdFusion for instance treats text that is surrounded by number signs (#) as a ColdFusion variable or function call.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is nothing called `##` in jquery. It would result in Syntax error.

However `#` in jquery specifies to select elements by their ID's. So if you write `#row` then it would match

```
<div id="row">
```

Check out this [Jquery reference](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/basic-css-selectors/).

**On a side note:-**

Hash `#` and `dot .` are the same as they are in CSS